# Installed Apache 2 with mod-mono behind code not executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, ubuntu, mono

I recently installed Apache 2. I have a.NET application built with Mono Develop. I know this application works because I have it running successfully on Microsoft IIS

I followed [the instructions on the Mono-Project site](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/) about installing and configuring mod-mono.

ASP.NET is working because my .aspx page does load but the C# in the CodeBehind is not executing, I looked in my Apache log file and there are no errors and I turned on "Debugging" level logging for more details but  nothing stands out to me.

I did not do anything special on the apache or mod-mono install just followed the instructions.

Has any one had this problem? Does it sound like I missed something?

My set up is:
Ubuntu-Mate: 16.04
apache2
mod-mono and mono-server4

Thank you

Comment: what version of mono is this?

Comment: version numbers are x.y.z, not just x

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is the version 4.2.3 (Stable 4.2.3.4/832de4b)

Comment: how did you install mono?

Comment: I followed these instructions: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/ ------Specifically the  Debian, Ubuntu, and derivatives